# Format Time as 24 Hours Military Format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert a date/time format that currently stores the Start Time of an event (Start_) to military time format without the colon ':'. So if the time is stored as 5:30pm it should come through as 1730

Code I have tried is below but it brings through the seconds and the colon.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, E.Start_, 108) 
FROM Events E
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and what you want.  Is the `time` being stored as a string?

Comment: What datatype is the column `E.Start`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just use `format()`:

```
select format(E.Start_, 'hhmm')
```

If you want a number:

```
select datepart(hour, E.Start_) * 100 + datepart(minute, E.Start_)
```